# ssh passwordless doesn't work for newly created user through “useradd” command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to setup a passwordless login from `machineA` to `machineB` for my user `david` which already exits and it works fine. This is what I did:

```
david@machineA:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
...

david@machineB:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
...
```

Generated authentication keys both on `machineA` and `machineB` for `david` user. After that I copied `id_rsa.pub` `(/home/david/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)` key of `machineA` into `machineB` `authorized_keys` file `(/home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys)` key.

And then I went back to machineA login screen and ran below command and it worked without asking for password:

```
david@machineA:~> ssh david@machineB
```

Now I created a new user without any password on `machineA` and `machineB` both by running this command only `useradd golden`. And now I want to ssh passwordless from this `golden` user to `machineB` from `machineA`. I did same exact step as above but it doesn't work.

```
david@machineA:~> sudo su - golden
golden@machineA:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
.......

david@machineB:~> sudo su - golden
golden@machineB:~> ssh-keygen -t rsa
.......
```

And then I copied `id_rsa.pub` key for golden user from machineA to machineB `authorized_keys` file. And when I try to ssh, it gives me:

```
golden@machineA:~> ssh golden@machineB
Connection closed by 23.14.23.10
```

What is wrong? It doesn't work only for golden user which I created manually through this command `useradd`. I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any settings that I need to enable for this manual user which I created?

**Update:**

```
golden@machineA:~$ pwd
/home/golden
golden@machineA:~$ ls -lrtha
total 60K
-rw------- 1 golden golden  675 Nov 22 12:26 .profile
-rw------- 1 golden golden 3.6K Nov 22 12:26 .bashrc
-rw------- 1 golden golden  220 Nov 22 12:26 .bash_logout
drwxrwxr-x 2 golden golden 4.0K Nov 22 12:26 .parallel
drwxr-xr-x 2 golden golden 4.0K Nov 22 12:34 .vim
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4.0K Dec 22 11:56 ..
drwx------ 2 golden golden 4.0K Jan  3 15:00 .ssh
-rw------- 1 golden golden  17K Jan  3 15:04 .viminfo
drwx------ 5 golden golden 4.0K Jan  3 15:04 .
-rw------- 1 golden golden 4.2K Jan  3 16:32 .bash_history


golden@machineB:~$ pwd
/home/golden
golden@machineB:~$ ls -lrtha
total 52K
-rw------- 1 golden golden  675 Dec 22 15:10 .profile
-rw------- 1 golden golden 3.6K Dec 22 15:10 .bashrc
-rw------- 1 golden golden  220 Dec 22 15:10 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root     4.0K Jan  3 14:26 ..
-rw------- 1 golden golden  11K Jan  3 15:21 .viminfo
drwx------ 2 golden golden 4.0K Jan  3 15:21 .ssh
drwx------ 6 golden golden 4.0K Jan  3 15:21 .
-rw------- 1 golden golden 2.9K Jan  3 15:27 .bash_history
```

Path for authorized_keys file is on machineB

```
/home/golden/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Since the verbose log is very big so I pasted it on gist here:

https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/cf49052039313e4c654183bf9eafd97c

**Another Update:**

In the machineB `auth.log` file, below is what I am seeing when I run this command from machineA `ssh -vvv golden@machineB` to login

```
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `golden' from `machineA'
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user golden: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: fatal: Access denied for user golden by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Comment: By passwordless, do you mean "able to login with an empty password" (password field='') or "unable to login with any password" (password field='*' for example)?

Comment: Did you create a home directory for user `golden` (`useradd -m`, depending on defaults on your system)?  Where did you place `authorized_keys` on machineB (full path)?  Did you ensure the permissions on `authorized_keys` and its containing directory were correct?

Comment: Yes home directory is there and that's why I copied id_rsa.pub for golden user of machineA into authorized_keys file for golden user in machineB. Yeah I made sure permissions were correct. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: Only thing is when I created `golden` user, I didn't added any password at all. Just ran `useradd golden` that's all.

Comment: Does `golden` have a valid login shell? Have you run ssh with verbose flags (`ssh -v` or `ssh -vv`) to see at what point the connection is closed?

Comment: The default for `useradd` is to disable the password. Thus this is not an empty password: the user can't login with a password. On the other hand, by default the user hasn't any shell defined, and that's why it can not login with ssh (credits to @steeldriver, post this as an answer)

Comment: @xhienne so what is the fix for this then?

Comment: @steeldriver Updated the question with verbose logging output as well.

Comment: The verbose log has as on line 95 `debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker`. Can you check that the first line of /home/golden/.ssh/id_rsa is `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- `  ?

Comment: You mean I should check in machineA or machineB? I checked both the machine and yes first line is that only..

Comment: I also saw this `http://stackoverflow.com/a/30592989/5447339` where they say this will occur even it is successfull login.

Answer (score 1):

`useradd` is a low level utility. `adduser` would have been a better choice. Here, your problem is that, by default, `useradd` creates a user without a shell. And [you can't do anything with `ssh` if you connect to a shell-less account](https://serverfault.com/questions/619914/ssh-without-invoking-shell/823466#823466).

The solution is to add a shell to your user:

```
chsh -s /bin/sh golden
```

Comment: Ok I added the shell. Do I have to execute all other command again for key generation? Or it will work now if I try to login? Bcoz I tried again and still I got same connection closed

Comment: @user5447339 This should work now. Can you `su` that user as root (no password required)? IMHO, you should try again from scratch with a new user created with `adduser` (caution: do not set an empty password).

Comment: I am logged in as `david` and then I am able to switch to golden user like this `sudo su - golden` without any password. This I was able to do before as well without running the command you suggested.

Comment: @user5447339 You're right, `su` default to `/bin/sh`